# Umbraco 7 Adding new languages to settings through code

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Umbraco 7.2.8 site.  We have managed to create a CI process, which includes migration of added fields, properties types etc.

We have not done Languages and I'm wondering if its possible.

So what I would like to know is if there is a way in code to add a new language to the Languages tab within Settings from code?

Thanks

Comment: Update: I found that ApplicationContext.Current.Services.LocalizationService.Save(new Language("es-ES")); works but Unfortunately the code that runs the migration does not have access to the ApplicationContext

Comment: That sounds like a seperate question ;) Have you included Umbraco.Core as a reference?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used or tested this myself but according to the source code it should be possible through the LocalizationService

```
var languageSE = new Language("sv-SE") { CultureName = "sv-SE" };
Services.LocalizationService.Save(languageSE);
```